# Integral Help: $\int^t_0{se^{d(t-s)} ds}$

Tags: definite-integrals

I would like to know how to solve this integral, I have tried and I know the solution. Yet, I am not able at all to work around all the steps to get to the solution. I know this is a particular case, but I do not know how to achieve the right solution. The integral is the following (in case the format in the title does not work).

$$\int^t_0{se^{d(t-s)} ds}$$

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\int se^{d(t-s)}ds=e^{dt}\int se^{-ds}ds$$

and now integration by parts may be handy.

Comment: Long time no see, *amigo* !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  C'est la vie, mon chéri ami!

Comment: *Mon ami*, please check the translation of *chéri* ! Regards, my friend !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hmmm...mon chér ami, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

for your control the result is given by $$\frac{-d t+e^{d t}-1}{d^2}$$